# kie-server-6.2.0-Final issues

Tags: java, drools, rules, kie

1). I have project in drools-workbench written some rules and deployed in container it gives one rest url (kie-server).
     I am trying to invoke the rest url through chrome extension rest plug-in or soap ui, first time got the response as expected, modified rules in workbench and build&deploy.
     If again hit the rest url its giving  previous response not modified one, means rules modifications are not reflecting in rest call.

2). Deployed rules in container (kie-server) goes down at certain time, if i need that containers always in running position what will be the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

are you ok?

At this time, i understand that you need to modify your rules, deploy and "put" the new jar that contains the rules project to execute in kie-server, right?

Follow this steps to do this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After click the last step, like the last print, now, you can see in the log of your server that the your jar is replaced for the last new jar that you created.

If isn't that you looking for, can you specifiy your question?

marcoblos.